# How to add header or request body using WcfCoreMtomEncoder .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, mtom

I'm creating .NET core application that communicates with WCF endpoint and returns MTOM.
I was able to do it with HttpWebRequest but i have a problem with adding additional elements to request.

I've found WcfCoreMtomEncoder lib that helps with that type of responses and I've implemented it like below:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();       
   
}     
myfunction(){
        XmlDocument body.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>  <soapenv:Envelope...");
         var encoding = new MtomMessageEncoderBindingElement(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement());
        var transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        transport.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        //transport.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        transport.ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;``
        
        var binding = new CustomBinding(encoding, transport);
        
           
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("myEndpointUrl");
        ChannelFactory<IService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, endpoint);
        //channelFactory.Credentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
       //channelFactory.Credentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = password;
        var webService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(webService.Test());
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            string pageContent = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
        }                                                                                     
}
```

**QUESTION**

How can I add additional Header attributes and a soap request body (body variable) to request?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add additional Header attributes or a soap request body,implement the interface called IDispatchMessageInspector.
Here the example:

```
 public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testrequest", "http://Test", "Test");
        OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
        Console.WriteLine("request"+request);
        return null;
    }

public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
        Console.WriteLine("reply"+reply);
    }
}
```

CustomMessageInspector  implements the interface called IDispatchMessageInspector.It contains a custom header to the message after getting it,and also adds a custom header before sending the message.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
   public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
   {
  dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
   }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   {
    return;
   }
}
```

Next we add the interceptor to the behavior of the service.

Finally we apply CustomBehavior to the service.